# "impute" as an intransitive verb

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

I came across a sentence in a Wikipedia article that went like this (MEMRI stands for Middle East Media Research Institute):

> In 2006, Finkelstein accused MEMRI of editing a television interview he gave in Lebanon in order to falsely impute that he was a Holocaust denier.
>   [MEMRI article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_East_Media_Research_Institute#Accusations_of_bias)

This sounded strange to me as I think I've always heard it as imputing 'something' to 'something/someone', meaning it's transitive. I know anyone can edit Wikipedia, so I didn't make much of it. However I did try to search for more instances of an intransitive use of *impute*. None of the dictionaries I've seen list "impute" as intransitive, but it is used in this way (relevant parts have been made bold by me.

> If a tweet advises readers not to leave their wallets lying around if John Smith's in the room, the meaning on which Mr Smith's lawyers will fight the case is that the words **impute that he's** a thief.
>   [Defamation law in the online age: for beginners - Sydney Morning Herald article](https://www.smh.com.au/opinion/defamation-law-in-the-online-age-for-beginners-20170803-gxoqdj.html)
>
> A statutory audit results in the auditor giving either an unqualified audit opinion so that the reader can **impute that the entitity's** financial statements reflect a 'true and fair view', or on the contrary an audit opinion that indicates...
>   [Health and Safety, Environment and Quality Audits: A risk-based approach, 2014](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=oSVrAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&dq=%22impute%20that%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjavrio_q7gAhWLaCsKHXhOACs4FBDoAQg8MAM#v=onepage&q=%22impute%20that%20the%22&f=false)
>
> I will not single out any of the many individuals who have been helpful, and, most importantly, I do not mean to **impute that the** contents of this work have passed their final muster.
>   [Stone Tools: Theoretical Insights Into Human Prehistory, 1996](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=rvi9uDDvC24C&pg=PA276&dq=%22impute%20that%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjavrio_q7gAhWLaCsKHXhOACs4FBDoAQhMMAY#v=onepage&q=%22impute%20that%20the%22&f=false)
>
> It stated that a defendant will have a ‘non-delegable’ duty of care when: ... There is a pre-existing relationship between the claimant and the defendant which places the claimant in the care or custody of the defendant and from which it is reasonable to **impute that the defendant** owes the claimant a ‘positive duty’ to protect him or her from harm;
>   [Boys & Maugham Solicitors website, a UK a law firm](https://www.boysandmaughan.co.uk/site/about/)
>
> The  Fifth  District  court  now  has  the  latitude  to  impute  whether  the  legislators  believed  they  were  taking  “the  only  course of action which appeared open” in adopting a piece of legislation, or it can **impute that the legislators** had no other options open to them.
>   [Analysis of a Florida Supreme Court decision in 2017](https://www.floridasupremecourt.org/content/download/345988/3056371/11-1484_JurisIni.pdf)
>
> Plaintiff first contends  that  the  statements  in  the  article  are  defamatory  per  se because they  **impute  that  the  Plaintiff**  has  committed  a  crime,  namely  the  illegal cyberattack.
>   [UNITED STATES DISTRICT COURT FOR THE NORTHERN DISTRICT OF ILLINOIS, Memorandum opinion and order.](https://www.courthousenews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Prometheus.pdf)
>
> Here, Dziagwa's alleged statement did not
>   fairly **impute that the plaintiff** had committed a car theft or any other indictable criminal offense.
>   [Illinois Appellate Court decision, 1997](http://www.illinoiscourts.gov/opinions/appellatecourt/1997/1stdistrict/august/html/1952801.txt)

I'm just wondering if this use is acceptable or standard.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that some of the quotations overlap 'impute' with 'imply' ? My understanding of 'impute' is a matter of transferring attribute.

Comment: @NigelJ I was thinking that maybe some may mix it with imply and impugn. Maybe these words play some part.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **impute** can be complemented by  a clause:

> Are you imputing that the company was negligent?

and by a noun phrase:

> Are you imputing negligence on the company's part?

and by  prepositional phrase + clause:

> Are you imputing to him that he intended to defraud the bank by exaggerating the worth of his collateral?
>
> An intention to defraud the bank has been imputed to him.
>
> That he intended to defraud the bank has been imputed to him.
>
> That he intended to defraud the bank has been imputed.
>
> Are you imputing to them that they were motivated by greed?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the first example impute is being used intransitively, right?

Comment: In old-school terms, right, it is not transitive in the sense that it has no direct object.

Comment: It has a direct object and it is transitive. There is no intransitive use of _impute_, *unless you impute. The direct object of _impute_ in the first example is the complement _that_-clause _that the company was negligent_. Complement clauses act as noun phrases and can be subjects or direct objects. The odd part about this construction is that _impute_ normally takes an indirect object in a _to_-phrase, as well as a direct object. Usually one imputes something to someone, but not here.

Comment: @John Lawler: That is not the "old-school" understanding (what BillJ calls "mickey mouse grammar") of direct object, as in "He painted the fence".

Comment: @JohnLawler This is where I'm confused, and I may have to ask another question about it. Definitions of "impute" give "attribute" and "ascribe" as synonyms. In "I impute that the company was negligent" I don't see "attribute" or "ascribe" being able to replace "impute", or at least if it can, I wouldn't understand it. The issue I'm having is that these words usually link a causative factor to a result. I'm not sure whether "impute" works differently from these other two words. I guess it does, I don't think I could say "I attribute/ascribe that the company was negligent"

Comment: @JohnLawler Also, the only way I can understand "I impute that the company was negligent" is in no way related to how the dictionaries define "impute", which say to attribute, ascribe, or relate two things. The only way I can understand it is if "impute" means "claim" or "accuse" or "charge", because it doesn't mention something that's related to the company having been negligent. Edit: or even "believe" or "consider", "I believe/consider that the company was negligent."

Comment: Impute (what?) he was a holocaust denier (noun phrase as direct object). Transitive: the verb carries the action to the object). Lawler's right. What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell most instances of *impute* used in this way come from subject matter dealing with law, and seem to have been more common in earlier times. However this usage seems to have carried on through into legal and legislative (parliamentary etc.) contexts and settings up to this day. Also, it seems that some people have adopted this type of use in writing or speaking about general topics, as shown in the stone tools book citation in my question, but there are also other examples I found, such as in *Figures of Simplicity: Sensation and Thinking in Kleist and Melville, 2010*, a book that analyzes literature from various authors.

I have checked the 1913 Webster's Dictionary and it only lists "impute" as a transitive verb. This is also the case in the 1828 edition of Webster's. I've also checked a law dictionary but its examples show a use which is consistent with all dictionaries, eg.:

> The mother's negligence can be imputed to the child in any claim on behalf of the child against the truck driver.
>   [The People's Law Dictionary](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=912)

Based on what I've seen, this intransitive usage is generally nonstandard, and when seen or heard it's likely said in a legal or parliamentary setting or context. Also, when impute is used in this way it seems to mean something like the intransitive *claim* or *charge*. Eg.:

> The Treasurer's legal team argues the Fairfax articles, published last May, impute that he is corrupt and accepted bribes,...
>   [Financial Times article](https://www.afr.com/business/legal/i-dont-instruct-or-control-north-sydney-forum-says-hockey-20150310-13zv74)

However there are plenty of examples of both individuals, media outlets and writers using it in this way in general terms, though I can't tell how common this is as a proportion of all uses of the word.

Also, I'm not sure if this is of any value, but a Google NGram search gave the following [result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impute%20that%20the%2C%20impute%20motives%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimpute%20that%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpute%20motives%20to%3B%2Cc0).